# Redirect on mobile *only* if specific anchor is present? (my current code redirects but ignores conditional)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, redirect, mobile

On mobile, I'd to redirect to the subdomain `store.website.com` only if the url is `website.com/#store`. If the url is not that, I'd to do redirect to the subdomain `m.website.com`. The following always redirects to the store subdomain if the url is simply `website.com`, store anchor or not:

```
var url = "http://website.com/#store";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
if (hash == "store") {
window.location.replace("http://store.website.com");
} else if (window.location.href == "http://website.com") {
window.location.replace("http://m.website.com");
}
```

I get the same result if I replace the 'else if' statement with a simple 'else' statement, or if I drop the else statement altogether. It always redirects to `store.website.com` in any case. Is there a slight adjustment I should make here to get the code to work as intended, or perhaps an altogether different method that should do the trick? Thanks

Comment: Side note; `window.location.hash` would return `#store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the variable `url` is always set to `http://website.com/#store`

```
var url = "http://website.com/#store";
```

Change this to:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

`window.location.href` will retrieve the current address. Then the hash should be correct.

or learn from this code using `location.hash` instead:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash == "#store")
{
    window.location.replace("http://store.website.com");
}
else if (window.location.hostname == "website.com")
{
    window.location.replace("http://m.website.com");
}
```

Fist we use `window.location.hash` to get the hash part and match it. If it doesn't pass check the host name. don't use the full url. If someone enters using HTTPS instead of HTTP it won't pass. So use `window.location.hostname` to match the domain name instead.

Be aware this code is going to affect not just mobile devices unless you check if a mobile device is been used otherwise desktop users are going to be redirected to `m.website.com` too.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, you are always updating the location because `hash` is always equal to `'store'`. You never get to the second `if`.

Maybe you should read the hash from `window.location.href` instead of the variable `url`.

Answer (score 1):

This small script would you :

```js
var hash = window.location.hash

hash && hash === "#store" ? window.location.replace("http://store.website.com") : window.location.replace("http://m.website.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is always a fixed String. You should check against `window.location.href` instead.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
if (hash == "store") {
window.location.replace("http://store.website.com");
} else if (url == "http://website.com") {
window.location.replace("http://m.website.com");
}
```